# Reformatting a PHP var_dump

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, var-dump

I just connected to a web service using SoapClient. The web service returns information regarding a vehicle based on a specific input, the vehicle's VIN. My `$result` variable is set equal to the web service output; thus, `var_dump ($result);` dumps all the vehicle information. I am having difficulty decoding it. Here is a portion of the output I received for an Audi VIN:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (14) {
    ["responseStatus"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
        ["responseCode"]=> string(10) "Successful"
        ["description"]=> string(10) "Successful"
    }
    ["vinDescription"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (11) {
        ["WorldManufacturerIdentifier"]=> string(17) "Germany Audi Nsu "
    }
}
```

How can I reformat the output? I want to pull the strings from it. For example, I would like to reformat the example output so that it reads like this:

Response: Successful 
World Manufacturer Id: Germany Audi Nsu

Here is my PHP code (I have omitted my username and password to the web service):

```html
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'vin' => $vin
]);



var_dump ($result);

?>
```

**___________________________________________________________________________**

Encountered another roadblock. It seems the further I dig into the data the more complex calling data to create new variables becomes. I am attempting to extract "Audi S4", "5 Door Wagon", and "All-Wheel Drive"

Here is the section I am struggling with:

```
["technicalSpecification"]=>
array(97) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#640 (2) {
  ["titleId"]=>
  int(1)
  ["value"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#641 (3) {
      ["styleId"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(292015)
        [1]=>
        int(292016)
      }
      ["value"]=>
      string(7) "Audi S4"
      ["condition"]=>
      string(3) "-PT"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#642 (3) {
      ["styleId"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(292015)
        [1]=>
        int(292016)
      }
      ["value"]=>
      string(7) "Audi S4"
      ["condition"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#643 (2) {
  ["titleId"]=>
  int(2)
  ["value"]=>
  object(stdClass)#644 (3) {
    ["styleId"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(292015)
      [1]=>
      int(292016)
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(12) "5 Door Wagon"
    ["condition"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#645 (2) {
  ["titleId"]=>
  int(6)
  ["value"]=>
  object(stdClass)#646 (3) {
    ["styleId"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(292015)
      [1]=>
      int(292016)
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "All-Wheel Drive"
    ["condition"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

**___________________________________________________________________________**

By adding:

```
$resultxml = htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";
echo $resultxml;
```

I am able to get the output in XML. Here is the data I am trying to pull from to form variables with:

```
 <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>1</titleId>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="-PT">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>2</titleId>
        <value value="5 Door Wagon" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>6</titleId>
        <value value="All-Wheel Drive" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var_dump` is usually ease for the programmer to test out the outcome of certain values like what you did. However in your case, if you are very sure the outcome of the return **data structure**, I suggest you to reformat the outcome by straight printing out the desired data:

**Wrong value-accessing demonstration script :**

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'vin' => $vin
]);

if(property_exists($result, 'responseCode') && property_exists($result,'WorldManufacturerIdentifier')){
    echo "Response : ".$result['responseStatus']['responseCode']."<br>World Manufacturer Id : ".$result['vinDescription']['WorldManufacturerIdentifier']."<br>";
}else{
    echo "The returned data is not complete!"; //or other proper error messages
}
?>
```

**The edited correct script is here :**

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'vin' => $vin
]);

if(property_exists($result, 'responseCode') && 
property_exists($result,'WorldManufacturerIdentifier')){
    echo "Response : ".$result->responseStatus->responseCode."<br>World Manufacturer Id : ".$result->vinDescription->WorldManufacturerIdentifier."<br>";
}else{
    echo "The returned data is not complete!"; //or other proper error messages
}
?>
```

For the latest XML part, you have to *wrap* extra tags around your XML result before you load it manually. Using [getElementsByTagName()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) and [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) allow me to load out the result with looping function:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<some><technicalSpecification><titleId>1</titleId><value 
value="Audi S4" condition="-PT"><styleId>292015</styleId> 
<styleId>292016</styleId></value><value value="Audi S4" condition=""> 
<styleId>292015</styleId><styleId>292016</styleId></value> 
</technicalSpecification><technicalSpecification><titleId>2</titleId><value 
value="5 Door Wagon" condition=""><styleId>292015</styleId> 
<styleId>292016</styleId></value></technicalSpecification> 
<technicalSpecification><titleId>6</titleId><value value="All-Wheel Drive" 
condition=""><styleId>292015</styleId><styleId>292016</styleId></value> 
</technicalSpecification></some>');
$childs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("technicalSpecification");
foreach($childs as $child){
    $value = $child->getElementsByTagName("value")[0]->getAttribute("value");
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: I attempted to call specific variables using similar code: `echo $result['WorldManufacturerIdentifier'];`. However, that command wasn't recognized.

Comment: @mugelloblue may i know the output error message when the error occured?

Comment: I've reformatted your received data to make it clearer how to get the data you want. Try `$result->vinDescription->WorldManufacturerIdentifier` or `$result['vinDescription']['WorldManufacturerIdentifier']`.

Comment: @mugelloblue Just as Greg mentioned I miss look the data structure and edited the answer, the data structure should be `$result[vinDescription'']['WorldManufacturerIdentifier']` instead of just `$result['WorldManufacturerIdentifier']`

Comment: @GregSchmidt @gitguddog Thanks so much for your additions. Yes, the data structure is what was giving me a hard time. It seems `$result->vinDescription->WorldManufacturerIdentifier` calls the data perfectly. While `$result['vinDescription']['WorldManufacturerIdentifier']` fails to call the data. Any ideas as to why one would prevail over the other? They seem to be the same statement?

Comment: @mugelloblue There are difference of accessing either **array** of **object** by using _brackets_ or _arrow notations_. You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181229/php-extracting-array-values-square-brackets-vs-arrow-notation/26181267#26181267) to get a clearer concept about the value accessing. btw Greg did a great job tho)

Comment: @gitguddoge ahhh yes object reference vs array reference. Thanks!

Comment: @mugelloblue welcome man, i learned something too :) will further edit the answer tho

Comment: @GregSchmidt @gitguddoge I am working my way down through the data and encountered a portion I am struggling to call. I am trying to extract 3 strings `Audi S4`, `5 Door Wagon`, and `All-Wheel Drive`. I edited the question to include this. Any help would again be very appreciated.

Comment: The indentation in your data is a mess, which makes it hard for anyone, including me and presumably you, to figure out what the real structure is. Have you used the `<pre>` suggestion from @NorielleCruz?

Comment: @mugelloblue as Greg mention could you use `<pre>` to format the outcome? It hard for us to look at the structure in such way

Comment: @GregSchmidt @gitguddoge I updated the beginning slightly, but that is how it is formatted with `<pre>`. Ever since @NorielleCruz recommended I have been using `<pre>`.  Also, added screen shots of the output. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mugelloblue I would suggest you to use the [Object Iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) where the concepts is to loop through the multidimensional array/object, you can first try level by level to check for the value for current level before you moved on

Comment: @mugelloblue let say for first level u can try `for($result as $k1 => $v1){print_r($v1);}` and after you find out that there is another level for `$v1` during loop u can add another level where something like `for($result as $k1 => $v1){for($v1 as $k2 => $v2){print_r($v2);}}` and just in case you mess up with the `$value` thing you can always use `$result[$k1]` to replace `$v1`

Comment: @gitguddoge I will check it out, thanks! The output is very simple in XML, maybe I can just change the `$Result` output to XML and try to pull the data directly from there.

Comment: @mugelloblue if the returned result is confirmed in xml format using [loadXML() from DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) is way better

Comment: @gitguddoge I just added the XML output and how I got it to the bottom of the question. Would you call that data in a similar fashion? Something like `$resultxml->$technicalSpecifications->and so on?` I will check out that link now, thanks!

Comment: @mugelloblue have a look since i able to get the value

Comment: @gitguddoge Still not able to get the value from `DomDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo an html **pre** element above it, it should look like this:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7b?wsdl');
$account = ['number'=>"", 'secret'=>"", 'country'=>"US",    'language'=>"en"];
$vin = $_POST["b12"];

$result = $client->describeVehicle([
'accountInfo' => $account,
'vin' => $vin
]);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump ($result);
echo "</pre>"; // optional       
?>
```

Alternatively, use **print_r()** instead.